# How to monitor Pages/sec and Page Faults/sec in MSSQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I need to analyze my databases' memory bottlenecks. Pages/sec and Page Faults/sec, Memory Grants Pending, Page Life Expectancy etc. How can I retrieve all this data?

Comment: Use extended events. SQL profiler is possible as well, however, it is deprecated.

Comment: SQL Server uses its own memory management. It doesn't allow its memory to be swapped out. The server manages various *buffers* according to usage. Memory and buffer usage metrics are available through Dynamic Management Views like [sys.dm_exec_query_memory_grants](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-exec-query-memory-grants-transact-sql), explained [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlqueryprocessing/2010/02/16/understanding-sql-server-memory-grant/). Typically though, you don't need such detail

Comment: Why do you think you have a *memory* bottleneck? It's far more likely that you don't have *enough* RAM, or/and there is an IO bottleneck. Insufficient RAM leads to higher usage of `tempdb` and IO issues, especially if tempdb isn't properly configured

Comment: Actually, i don't have, i'm trying to learn performance analyze. Memory, disk I/O so on. Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

> i need to analyze my databases' memory bottlenecks. Pages/sec and Page Faults/sec, Memory Grants Pending, Page Life Expectancy etc. How can i retrieve all these data?

This data is all stored in <kbd>[sys.dm_os_performance_counters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-os-performance-counters-transact-sql)</kbd>

```
select * from sys.dm_os_performance_counters 
where counter_name like '%grants%'
```

below is one sample screenshot on my developer instance

[image]

You must also note the counter value for some objects are cumulative,so you will need to gather them and find difference between time intervals to find actual values..